# Fetch current user through store.find('users', 'me') stores invalid User instance

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am trying this solution to fetch the current user before my application is rendered to the user:

```
Em.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        var currentUserPromise = this.store.find('user', 'me');

        return Em.RSVP.all([
            currentUserPromise
        ]);
    }
});
```

So, I query the `user` with the ID `me`, which is a constant that my API recognizes as the currently authenticated user.

It  works really well most of the way. The issue is that Ember-Data immediately creates a User model in the store with this ID constant `me` and no other attributes. This instance is not removed after the response has arrived and Ember-Data correctly stores the real User model.

[image: The temporary and real instances]

I can't figure out where Ember-Data creates this temporary instance and if there is a way to prevent this behavior.

Either a solution to prevent Ember-Data from creating the temp. instance or remove it when the real data arrives will be fine.

Anyone with a solution?

Comment: which version of ember data are you using? in ember-data 1.0.0.beta-8 this works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After consulting with #emberjs I found that a much cleaner solution to this challenge is to request the active user by requesting a session object from my API.

By exposing a `/sessions` endpoint in my API I could expose the current session—which can also include auth token, etc.—with a relationship to the currently logged in profile. That resulted in a JSON payload like this:

```
{
  "sessions": [
    { 
      "id": 1, 
      "user": { ... }, 
      "accessToken": "abcdef1234567890" 
    }
  ]
}
```

This means that I will no longer have the issue that Ember-Data caches a bogus User object with the id 'me', instead I will now have a session object where the active user is correctly loaded into the store and have it available through the session.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going about things the wrong way. You're in a single page application, which means the user can log out or log in at any time, and any rendering is essentially already happening before and after that. You can only control what you allow to render, but not the when.

Also, you are explicitly returning a set of promises which resolves when the single promise it contains is resolved. This achieves the same:

```
Em.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('user', 'me');
    }
});
```

You don't know when that will resolve, but you're asking to "fetch the user before the app is rendered to the user". That's not how it works in Ember, as you can't really delay rendering. (Technically you can, but that offers terrible user experience giving the feeling the browser has locked up).

What you would want to do instead is to modify what you are rendering based on the state of the logged in user, and on the backend side you only ever send what that user is allowed to see. Anything else is insecure, as you can't ever trust the browser. It's pretty trivial to make an Ember app think you are logged in.

> The issue is that Ember-Data immediately creates a User model in the store with this ID constant me and no other attributes.

I'm not sure about that one; I'm guessing ember-data creates a placeholder while it waits for the population of the real data (if ever). It is as if you're creating a new empty object in code.

> I can't figure out where Ember-Data creates this temporary instance

Ember-data is in its core basically a cache (why it is called the store) with various adapters to read from and write to that cache and an API to use it. In your example `me` is created in the cache only, at least until you decide to save it.

Comment: 1. The code I posted was only part of my actual application, I had more promises that needed to be resolved, thus the `RSVP.all` presence. 2. The problem is exactly the cache. I did find a more clean solution where I am fetching the active user through a `/session` endpoint and `session` model.

Answer (score 0):

Ember data modifies the same record instead of creating a new record after the materialization. There might be some other problem while finding the records for table. For example In ember data 1.0.0-beta.8 the the following code logs correct id rather than printing 'me'.

```
this.store.find('user', 'me').then(function(user) {
   console.log(user.get('id'));
});
```